# Why is /data modify not editing signs correctly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the following commands:

```
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text1 set from entity @e[limit=1,tag=test] CustomName
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text2 set from entity @e[limit=1,tag=test] Health
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text3 set from entity @e[limit=1,tag=test] Attributes[0].Base
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text4 set from entity @e[limit=1,tag=test] HurtTime
```

Those are just examples but for some reason, only the `CustomName` works. None of the other commands work, although I have no idea why.

I'm playing on a server and I was using a pig to test this.

Comment: Because "Custom name" has text value, health has other type of value. But i don't know how to transfer it to text.

Answer (score 2):

As you may or may not know, the text tags of signs are JSON text tags, meaning they have to be entered in a certain format. The only reason the custom name works is because it is also a JSON text tag. The others are not JSON text tags, so they can't be written directly to the sign text tags.

The only alternative is to use the raw JSON text `nbt` element which tells the JSON text reader to check for NBT and render it. Try this:

```
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text2 set value '{"nbt":"Health","entity":"@e[limit=1,tag=test]"}'
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text3 set value '{"nbt":"Attributes[0].Base","entity":"@e[limit=1,tag=test]"}'
data modify block -107 78 -525 Text4 set value '{"nbt":"HurtTime","entity":"@e[limit=1,tag=test]"}'
```

Note that in order to correctly render the `nbt` element, the system has to convert them into `text` elements instead with the correct value. This is  called component resolution. This resolution can only happen with signs, and some select other areas.